# Replacing old windows - how to make vapor barrier?

Tags: windows, vapor-barrier, remodeling

I'm replacing a couple windows in an 80 year old house.  Not surprisingly, there is no house wrap or any kind of vapor barrier.  It's 2x4 studs with 1/2" tongue and groove wood siding on the inside, and 3/4" tongue and groove wood siding on the outside.  I don't see any moisture damage in here.  What is the correct way to deal with this?  It seems kind of pointless to buy flashing tape and seal the window to the studs only...

I live in Southern California, averaging 18 inches of rain per year.

Comment: How are the existing windows set to the wall from the outside? Directly over the studs or over the 3/4" wood siding? A picture would help. Usually, in old homes, there is a 3/4" subsiding that the windows are set to, then the siding is nailed over the subsiding and the cut ends meet the window trim. FWIW, the rough openings are huge if the windows are double hung, the window weights take up a lot of extra space in the framing that you don't see in the finish, about 4-5" each side

Comment: The existing windows are nailed directly to the studs, is that what you mean? The frame is wide enough that it overhangs the siding all around. But there is no subsiding; the tongue and groove is nailed directly to the studs.